# looping of mysql select query

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
For Each row In Item_Get(42, returnno)
    Dim barcode As String = Item_Get(42, returnno)
    Dim wh, sa, bo As Integer
    wh = Stat_Get(0, barcode)
    sa = Stat_Get(1, barcode)
    bo = Stat_Get(2, barcode)
    chk = Stock_Chk(0, barcode)
    If chk = True Then
        Stock_Update(barcode, wh, sa, bo)
    Else
        Stock_Save(barcode, wh, sa, bo)
    End If
Next
```

the `item_get(42, returno)` query is "select barcode as str from tblreturn where `status = '1' and returnno = @chk"`

the problem is it is not looping with the whole returned result. Can anyone help me here ?

Comment: What is actually happening?

Comment: @IsaacMorris it only updates one result. but the actual result returning in query is more than 1.

Comment: if you do Dim somvar = Item_Get(42, returnno)    does it return a collection.  if not your code is not seeing more then one object to loop

Comment: what should i do then ?

Comment: what is  Item_Get(42, returnno) actually returning?

Comment: it returns only 1 result. but when i tried the query in mysql workbench it is returning more than 1 result.

Comment: it should return this 2 barcode
4800194158961123123
4808887040012321321
but in the system. it is only returning the 4800194158961123123 code.

Comment: are there any differences beween how  Item_Get(42, returnno) runs the query vs how mysql workbench runs the query?

Comment: there are no differences on it. that's why i'm confused

Comment: what happens if you change For Each row In Item_Get(42, returnno) to For Each row In (select barcode as str from tblreturn where status = '1' and returnno = @chk")

Comment: it is still the same

Comment: do you have a test database so that you can create database values without harming the original database?

Comment: i'm using the test database. no worries.

Comment: what happens if there are 3 barcodes that should be returned?

Comment: still the same. still returning 1 result =/

Comment: and work bench is returning all 3

Comment: yes. i'm really confused right now.

Comment: i think there's something wrong with my for loop ?

Comment: What happens inside the Item_Get method?

Comment: "select barcode as str from tblreturn where status = '1' and returnno = @chk"

this is the query and it is returning more than 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

Within the `For` loop you should not get your data from `Item_Get(42, returnno)`
 but instead from `row`. That means something like `Dim barcode As String = row.item(0)`